# SonarQube 4.5.1 fails with "wrapper" complaint

Tags: sonarqube

Following the SonarQube documentation at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade I tried to run sonarqube but got an unexpected error:

```
[bdunn@va-play-bdunn101 local]$ sudo sonarqube/bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh console
Running SonarQube...
sonarqube/bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh: line 410: /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.1/bin/macosx-universal-64/./wrapper: cannot execute binary file
```

I confirmed that the path to java is correct in the wrapper.conf file.

Looking at sonar.sh, I see this:

```
403    console() {
404        echo "Running $APP_LONG_NAME..."
405        getpid
406        if [ "X$pid" = "X" ]
407        then
408            # The string passed to eval must handles spaces in paths correctly.
409            COMMAND_LINE="$CMDNICE \"$WRAPPER_CMD\" \"$WRAPPER_CONF\" wrapper.syslog.ident=$APP_NAME wrapper.pidfile=\"$PIDFILE\" $ANCHORPROP $LOCKPROP"
410            eval $COMMAND_LINE
411        else
412            echo "$APP_LONG_NAME is already running."
413            exit 1
414        fi
415    }
```

I see this:

```
[bdunn@va-play-bdunn101 local]$ file sonarqube/bin/macosx-universal-64/wrapper 
sonarqube/bin/macosx-universal-64/wrapper: Mach-O fat file with 2 architectures
```

Beyond this I am not sure what next to try.

Comment: On what Mac are you trying to run SonarQube? Looks like you're on an "old" architecture that is not supported by the wrapper.

Comment: i'm on an iMac running OSX 10.9.5.